# How do i give my link a color when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hy,

I'm currently working on this website and i need to be able to click on a link en that should open a div en close again when clicked. This i've already done. But my question is how do i make the link stay #0083ce when clicked. I've tried somethings but they do not seem to work together with my other javascript (for the div's).

```
function newwindow1(ele) {      
    var links = ['Profiel','Verbinder','Plaatjes','Moeren','Bouten','Scharnieren',
                 'Stelvoeten','Montage','Joints','Afdekken','Netten','Rails','Shuiven',
                 'Toebehoren','Quickboy'];
    var srcElement = document.getElementById(ele);      
    var doShow = true;        
    if(srcElement != null && srcElement.style.display == "block")
        doShow = false;
    for( var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i )    {
        var otherElement = document.getElementById(links[i]);      
        if( otherElement != null )
            otherElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
    if( doShow )
        srcElement.style.display='block';         
    return false;

}
```

Comment: I think you need to be more clear about what you're asking. The answers so far have suggested using the `:visited` selector, but I'm not sure if you mean something else.

Answer (score 3):

**css**

```
a:visited {
    color:#0083ce;
}
```

Visited css selector

```
a:active {
    color:#0083ce;
}
```

Active for when you actually click down on a link.

Comment: This is not what i mean. I mean that when you click it, the color stays. Like this, when it's unclicked its transparant and when it's clicked it should be blue

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use :visited, :active values to set required colour. eg:

```css
.classname:active {
  color: #994;
  /*any color*/
}
.classname:visited {
  //color: #F00;
  /*any color*/
}
```

```html
<a class="classname" href="#">Test</a>
```

Comment: If your going to post a code snippet you have to make sure it can run. your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer link for getting different colors

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a CSS rule, define a style called `.active`, for example:

```
.active { color: #0083ce; }
```

In you JavaScript, you need to set a class to active on `srcElement`
and make sure to remove that class in the `otherElement` loop.

You need to use something like `srcElement.className`.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

```js
function newwindow1(ele) {      
    var links = ['Profiel','Verbinder','Plaatjes','Moeren','Bouten','Scharnieren',
                 'Stelvoeten','Montage','Joints','Afdekken','Netten','Rails','Shuiven',
                 'Toebehoren','Quickboy'];
    var srcElement = document.getElementById(ele);      
    var doShow = true;        
    if(srcElement != null && srcElement.style.display == "block")
        doShow = false;
    for( var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i )    {
        var otherElement = document.getElementById(links[i]);      
        if( otherElement != null )
            otherElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
    if( doShow )
      {
        srcElement.style.display='block';         
        srcElement.className='active';         
    }
  return false;

}
```

```css
.active {color: blue;}
```

```html
<div id="Profiel" onclick="newwindow1('Profiel');">Profiel</div>
<div id="Verbinder" onclick="newwindow1('Verbinder');">Verbinder</div>
```